# An application of open mapping theorem for polynomial mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $0< \alpha<1$ and $q(z)=1+a_1z+\ldots+a_nz^n$ be a polynomial such that all the zeros of $q(z)$ have norm at least $\frac{1}{\alpha}$. If 
\begin{align*}
A_\alpha= \{q(z): |z|=\frac{1}{\alpha}\}, \quad A_1= \{q(z): |z|=1\},
\end{align*}
does it hold that the region bounded by $A_1 \subseteq $ region bounded by $A_\alpha$? I am trying to prove that it holds. By region bounded by a closed curve $C$, I mean the interior of $C$ together with the boundary.

My attempt: I feel that somehow this problem can be approached through open mapping theorem but not able to see the connection. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Do you mean to look at the regions bounded by $A_\alpha$ and $A_1$ in the complex plane?  It is unlikely that $A_1 \subseteq A_\alpha$ as stated.

Comment: @JairTaylor: Yeah, that's what I meant. I will edit the question.